# Does doxygen predefine any macros?

Tags: doxygen

Apart from the `PREDEFINED` configuration option, where I could always put `DOXYGEN=1`, does doxygen predefine any preprocessor macros prior to reading C++ files?

My train of thought is that GCC predefines macros such as `__GNUC__`, and MSC predefines macros such as `_MSC_VER`. Does doxygen predefine macros at all, such as `_DOXYGEN_VER`?

I don't want to use the `PREDEFINED` configuration option at all.

Answer (score 3):

No, Doxygen does not predefine any self-identifying tokens.

If you don't want to litter your code with preprocessor `#ifdef _DOXYGEN_VER / #endif` blocks you can use the [`\cond` command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond). The `\cond` command is an easier way to define sections that may be conditionally included/excluded similar to what you used to have to do with the C preprocessor tokens.

Comment: Actually, I wished that DOXYGEN would predefine at least two preprocessor macros: eG. DOXYGEN, and DOXYGEN_INTERNAL.

The reason is to document #defines that wouldn't be documented otherwse:


Such as:

#if defined(DOXYGEN) || defined(_MSC_VER)

#yada